# Run-length compression on an RGB image

Tags: image, compression, run-length-encoding

Suppose I have an RGB image with 3 bit color depth as displayed below. My uncompressed image size would therefore be `width * height * color depth` in my case `200 * 200 * 3 = 120000` bits.

What would be the image size if I use run-length compression? Let's suppose the length is stored using 1 byte.

[image: Run-length example image]

This is how I tried solving it, but I'm not sure if my solution is correct:

`20 * (1 + 3) + 160 * (1 + 3 + 1 + 3 + 1 + 3) + 20 * (1 + 3) = 2080` bits.

Compression ratio would therefore be `uncompressed / compressed = ratio` in my case `120000 / 2080 = 57.69`.

Comment: Seems fairly reasonable. You might like to read up on PCX format which worked like that https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track but although you have said your RLE counter will be one byte you have only allocated it one bit. s/1 +/8 +/ fixes that problem:

"What would be the image size if I use run-length compression? Let's suppose the length is stored using 1 byte."

20 * (8 + 3) + 160 * (8 + 3 + 8 + 3 + 8 + 3) + 20 * (8 + 3) =  5720 bits

There is another minor glitch in that you also need to be able to recognize when the bitstream is a colour index and when it is a counter. There are two common ways to do this. The most obvious is to prefix colour indexes with a 0 bit so 0rgb and counters with a 1 bit 1bbbbbbbb which then gives

20 * (9 + 4) + 160 * (9 + 4 + 9 + 4 + 9 + 4) + 20 * (9 + 4) =  6760 bits

The other method which wins or breaks even for images with 4 or fewer colours  is to use two copies of the colour index itself to escape in a counter. So for your test image and 8 colour palette that gives

20* (8 + 6) +  160 * (8 + 6 + 8 + 6 + 8 + 6) + 20 * (8 + 6) =  7280 bits

Assuming 24bit rgb palette colours to be stored you also need 24 bits for each distinct colour in the image and another 3 bits for a counter to say how many are used. Real image headers have a lot more info in them.

Wikipedia has a nice article on [RLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding)

Compression ratios somewhere between 16.5 and 20 for your sample image.

BTW your sample image only has two distinct colours used and so could be encoded 1 bit per pixel. (and then escaping in a counter by repeating a colour works rather well)

Comment: I fell into the trap of encoding it line by line. You can do much better by considering it as a pure bitstream B(20*200+20)[R(160)B(40)](160)B(20*200-20) which I think becomes: 16*(8+3) + 160*(8+3+8+3)+16*(8+3) = 3872 bits give or take back of envelope errors.